# Profiling a Maven build and performance tips

Tags: maven, build, maven-3

I have a maven build that runs for about an hour and 10 minutes. It is of a huge product. I am trying to understand the reason it takes that much time by profiling the build then start understanding what to change from there.

I am a bit lost on how to profile it. I tried using Jprofiler but the problem is that I couldn't get it to connect to the maven build JVM and was unable to get any results.

Any tips are appreciated!

(looked over the most popular similar questions on stackoverflow but nothing was actually helpful other than suggesting Jprofiler which did not work).

Comment: Is this build a multi-module build? Have you taken a look into the log output during the build in particular about the tests how long they take ? Can you post an log file output ?

Comment: Have you tried running with mvn clean install -DskipTests (i.e. do you have long running tests)?

Comment: Which are the modules which take the most parts of the time? What do they do?

Answer (score 0):

Add these arguments to your Maven build

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
```

Then run

`java/bin/jvisualvm`

The running build must appear in the list of possible JVMs to profile.